# How to store a plus sign in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, variables, web

I want to store a plus sign in a PHP variable, but it's not accepting it.

I tried to store `+92444444` in variable `$num`. But when I echo it, it gives me the result `92444444`.

Where did the plus sign go? How to store this number `+92444444` in a PHP variable?

Comment: What are you trying to store it as?  An integer or a string? Show your code.  Plus signs aren't used in integers, numbers are always positive unless there is a negative sign.

Comment: because you are storing an int and not a string ???

Comment: just a `$num = "+9244444444";` works totally fine actually

Comment: you should store it inside the quotes so as a string like `$num = "+9999" `otherwise it will be an `Integer`.

Comment: $smsqu = mysqli_query($mysqli,$smsq);

              while($smsrow = mysqli_fetch_array($smsqu))

              {

                  $phnum = $smsrow['phone'];

               echo "<script>alert($phnum);</script>"; 

              }

this is my code. the phone number is coming from database. there the number is +923139445123  but when i output it in alert, it give me result 923139445123. the "+" is not coming there. why?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding a string inside an int variable. These are some example how variable's will result output:

`$integer = 11;
$variableAndString = '+' . 11;
$string = '+12342';`

`$integer will output 11
$variableAndString will output +11
$string will output +1234`

Comment: $smsqu = mysqli_query($mysqli,$smsq); while($smsrow = mysqli_fetch_array($smsqu)) { $phnum = $smsrow['phone']; echo "<script>alert($phnum);</script>"; } this is my code. the phone number is coming from database. there the number is +923139445123 but when i output it in alert, it give me result 923139445123. the "+" is not coming there. why?

Comment: in the database the phone number is +923139445123. but when i retrieve it and display in alert it gives me 923139445123.

Comment: Did you tried to output $smsrow['phone'] what are you getting in that?